# MVVM CustomAttribute Property in Parameter

Tags: c#, mvvm, attributes

I created a custom attribute [NotExistToAddConfiguration] and would allow specifying the property of my ViewModel like this :

```
[RaisePropertyChanged]
[Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.Required)]
public virtual string Pata_Idtab { get; set; }

[RaisePropertyChanged]
[Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.Required)]
[NotExistToAddConfiguration(ErrorMessage = "Existe Deja",_Pata_Idtab = Pata_Idtab)]
```

My attribute

```
public  class NotExistToAddConfiguration : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        bool NotExist = false;
        NotExist = DalConfiguration.GetIDNotExist(Convert.ToString(value).Trim(), _Pata_Idtab);

        return NotExist;
    }
    public  string _Pata_Idtab { get; set; }

    public NotExistToAddConfiguration()
    {

    }
}
```

but its not working, an idea ?

Comment: Does your other validation attributes works (for example, Required)? What code make it work?

Comment: in made with Pata_Idtab I get an error an object reference is required for the property, method, or the non-static field

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It doesn't compile, it doesn't validate, it leads to exception?

Comment: It doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Your error depends on [Compiler Error CS0120](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx). It means that you are trying to have an access to the non static field from a static context.

In the code

```
[NotExistToAddConfiguration(ErrorMessage = "Existe Deja",_Pata_Idtab = Pata_Idtab)]
```

you can't access to the object variables, only to the class variables (static). You can change your code to initialize `_Pata_Idtab` with static variable or change `IsValid` method to check condition without that field.

Also remember that there is no default support for DataAnnotations in WPF. There are two ways to implement validation in WPF.

1. Use exception based validation. In data binding expression you can turns on validation on exception like in the code below:

   ```
   <TextBox Name=«age» Grid.Row=«1» Grid.Column=«1» Width=«200» Margin=«5» Text="{Binding Path=Age, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
   ```
2. Implement [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.100).aspx) in your class. There is a guide on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909868(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you have complex validation rules that requires few fields to check one condition it'll be better to use second one validation implementation.